# .NET 4.0 Release Candidate

Tags: .net, wpf

I just came across [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2009/12/18/wpf-performance-on-tablet-touch-enabled-machines.aspx) about WPF performance on Touch/Tablet devices.  In the article, the .NET Framework release candidate is mentioned as a way to test if this issue is affecting your application.  I'm only aware of the .NET Framework 4.0 Beta 2; is there a RC build of .NET Framework 4 available somewhere? Perhaps he just means the Beta 2.

Comment: There is only the Beta 2 available ATM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on when the article was posted they probably meant an internal build after Beta 2 since the RC build has not been released yet. According to [@scottgu](http://twitter.com/scottgu) on twitter they are currently testing some potential RC's but have not set a date. It has been mentioned that they are *very close* and the new VS has much much better performance. You can always try Beta 2 to see if you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

They could be testing RC in house before releasing it... Otherwise it is most likely a slip up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which build the author is talking about but the latest fully publicly available build is Beta2.  RC is scheduled for sometime in the near future (not sure about the actual date).

Answer (score 1):

It's not out publicly yet, I don't believe.  However, I believe some internal and ND testers have access to it at this point, as part of a "Super-Limited Community Technology Preview".

For details, see this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/12/17/vs-2010-net-4-public-release-candidate-planned.aspx).